# PloneCMS SPNEGO cannot find entry in keytab

Tags: python, single-sign-on, kerberos, spnego, plone-4.x

I am using netsight.windowsauthplugin version 2.3.1 in my Plone CMS installation on a linux server. The domain/realm is a windows domain.
My sysadmin gave me a .keytab file and set up the DNS A and PTR record, I have configured /etc/krb5.conf (the same way I have it for a spring java webapp on an another server), configured zope, but when I try to log in with Intrernet Explorer from my pc, I get an error:

> GSSError: (('Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more
>   information', 851968), ('No key table entry found matching HTTP/@',
>   39756033))

What am I missing? My plone python interpreter cannot resolv a proper name? It cannot read the keytab or krb5.conf file?

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot that can/could go wrong (or has to go right) before SSO works. To focus directly on your error report it seems that the PAS plugin in Plone cannot correctly get the GSSAPI service name.

In the latest master version on github (https://github.com/netsight/netsight.windowsauthplugin) there is a 'GSSAPI service' property you can add to the SPNEGO object stored in acl_users. Use this version and set the GSSAPI Service property to 'HTTP@www.mydomain.com'.

Note the '@' here, I think this is also wrong in the default value netsight.windowsauthplugin calculates where it adds a '/' as separator (suggesting it's an SPN, but it is the GSSAPI servide hint to the kerberos library.

If you run into other problems after this, please first try to enable kerberos library tracing by adding a KRB5_TRACE=/location/to/krbtrace-mysite.log environment variable before you start your Plone site (assuming you can run it from the terminal on some unixy environment). This KRB5_TRACE only works with newer kerberos releases but will provide you a lot more insight as to what is going wrong when you have to debug any further.